# PHP - Syncing two identical tables from SQL Server and MySQL and inserting only the differences, but code runs very slowly

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

The way my current code works, it selects all data from the first DB (SQL Server) and then also selects all data from MySQL, and then inserts only the differences. Problem is with tables with over 70k+ rows and photo files in it, it runs really slow and consumes a lot of memory. Here is a sample code from one of the smaller tables:

```
$mssql_array = array();
$ms_sql = "SELECT * FROM SALARY";
$mssql_query = sqlsrv_query($conn_mssql , $ms_sql);

while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($mssql_query))
{

  $mssql_array[] = array('SGRADE' => $row['SGRADE'], 'STEP' => $row['STEP'], 'AMOUNT' => $row['AMOUNT'], 'REMARK' => $row['REMARK'], 'unique' => $row['unique']);

}

foreach($mssql_array as $key => $value)
{

   //SELECT FROM MySQL DB
   $my_sql = " SELECT * FROM SALARY WHERE SGRADE ='".$value['SGRADE']."' AND STEP = '".$value['STEP']."' AND AMOUNT = '".$value['AMOUNT']."' AND REMARK = '".$value['REMARK']."' AND `unique` = '".$value['unique']."' ";
   $mysql_query = mysqli_query($conn_mysql , $my_sql);
   $num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($mysql_query);

   $sql = $conn_mysql->prepare("INSERT INTO salary VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"); 
   $sql->bind_param("sidsi", $SGRADE, $STEP, $AMOUNT, $REMARK, $unique);
   $SGRADE = $value['SGRADE'];
   $STEP = $value['STEP'];
   $AMOUNT = $value['AMOUNT'];
   $REMARK = $value['REMARK'];
   $unique = $value['unique'];

   if ($num_rows == 0)
   {
     //INSERT INTO MySQL DB
     $sql->execute();
   }
}
```

While it works really fast (less than 5secs) for small tables, for big tables it takes up about 2-3 hours (300k+ rows with 60 columns). I have something in mind that might make this code faster, which is to do a select max(*) query on the SQL Server table's primary key column ("unique" in above table's case), taking only the last row's 'unique' number and comparing that to MySQL's last row's 'unique'. if the SQL Server's 'unique' column value is higher than MySQL's, it then inserts all the unmatched records between the two tables. Thing is, I don't know how to translate this to code, or if it even is possible. Any ideas, or alternatives that I can use compared to the I'm using above?

Comment: why you are creating an array of all records first? what's the point in having lines 7-13 at all?

Comment: what is "unique" value? is it really unique? in case it is, why you're checking everything else in your select query?

Comment: Why you're using a prepared statement only for insert but not using it for select query?

Comment: im creating an array of all records for both tables because that's how im comparing their contents. yes, "unique" is a unique value (hence why i said its my primary key column) and is also auto incrementing. not using a prepared statement for the select query was an earlier mistake that i made, when i moved on to making this program for larger tables i made sure to do that but since it didnt cause any problems for this smaller table i didn't fix it. anyway, i don't see how all these questions are related to what im asking.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the new code I made:

```
$mssql_result = sqlsrv_query($conn_mssql, "SELECT MAX([unique]) FROM salary");
$mssql_row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($mssql_result);
echo $mssql_row[0];

$mysql_result = mysqli_query($conn_mysql, "SELECT MAX(`unique`) FROM salary");
$mysql_row = mysqli_fetch_array($mysql_result);
echo $mysql_row[0];

if($mssql_row[0] != $mysql_row[0])
{
  //SELECT FROM SQL SERVER DB
  $mssql_array = array();
  $ms_sql = "SELECT * FROM SALARY where [unique] > $mysql_row[0]";
  $mssql_query = sqlsrv_query($conn_mssql , $ms_sql);

  while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($mssql_query))
  {
    $mssql_array[] = array('SGRADE' => $row['SGRADE'], 'STEP' => $row['STEP'], 'AMOUNT' => $row['AMOUNT'], 'REMARK' => $row['REMARK'], 'unique' => $row['unique']);
  }

  foreach($mssql_array as $key => $value)
  {
    $sql = $conn_mysql->prepare("INSERT INTO salary VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"); 
    $sql->bind_param("sidsi", $SGRADE, $STEP, $AMOUNT, $REMARK, $unique);
    $SGRADE = $value['SGRADE'];
    $STEP = $value['STEP'];
    $AMOUNT = $value['AMOUNT'];
    $REMARK = $value['REMARK'];
    $unique = $value['unique'];
    $sql->execute();
  }
}
else
{
  echo "No new records to add!";
}
```

Now it no longer selects everything just to check and compares only the max row values based on the "unique" column. Runs so much faster than before.